# Loading GIF vs rotating css img

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I am trying to make a loading img display while an iframe is loading and I've noticed that the rotating css img version is slowing down my sites performance quite a bit. So should I go with a GIF instead?

Comment: A bit of code to see what you got would be nice. But I don't think it should be that big of a difference.

Comment: I was using the code from the bottom example in the w3school example [find here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the setTimeOut() part of that code you linked to.  It's only there for demonstration purposes otherwise the page would load too fast to see the loader. Remove that part of the code and just call the showPage() function.  Assuming you've copied the rest of the code exactly you'll just need to change the code at bottom to:

```
function myFunction() {
showPage();
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```